# Ad pass force change at next login from c#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to set AD to force password change on next login. I'm using Okta pointed to our AD server.

I do have okta fail to let me in on first login.

If I goto an old app and change the password when prompted it works. and then I can go back to the new app and suddenly can log in.  So I believe that okta is detecting the "force password change on next login" for the users first login.

When I run the code below, which is supposed to trigger it again,  and am perfectly able to login. (When I expect to fail, due to force password change on next login)

In ad, I think pwdLastSet = 0x0 is supposed to be the flag,  and that is getting set for the user. But it's not blocking my login like the first time.

I just log in normally.

```
private void button_adNameForcePassReset_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            string adServer          = "";
            string adServerUser      = "";
            string adServerPassword  = "";
            string adServerContainer = "";

            GetSettings( ref adServer, ref adServerUser, ref adServerPassword, ref adServerContainer );

            if ( ( ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( adServer ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( adServerUser ) ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( adServerPassword ) ) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty( adServerContainer ) )
            {
                try
                {
                    using ( PrincipalContext principalContext = GetPrincipalContextSecure() )
                    {
                        using ( UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( principalContext, IdentityType.SamAccountName, textBox_adNameForcePassReset.Text ) )
                        {
                            user.ExpirePasswordNow();

                            DirectoryEntry de        = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();

                            de.RefreshCache(  new[] { "PasswordExpired", "pwdLastSet" } );
                            if ( de.Properties.Contains( "PasswordExpired" ) )
                                de.Properties[ "PasswordExpired" ].Value = 1;

                            de.Properties[ "pwdLastSet" ].Value = 0;
                            de.CommitChanges();

                            user.Save();

                            if ( user.LastPasswordSet  != null)
                            {
                                FlexibleMessageBox.Show( "user.LastPasswordSet=" + user.LastPasswordSet );
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    FlexibleMessageBox.Show( ex.ToString() );
                }
                FlexibleMessageBox.Show( "Force Pass Reset done" );
            }
        }
```

Comment: There are a lot of grammar and spelling mistakes in your question that make it difficult to understand what your issue is. Would you rewrite your question?

Comment: any solution about it? what's is the issue?